# Ionic 4 SQLite : then and catch does not run

Tags: javascript, angular, database, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have created a database service in my ionic app, when i call the createDatabase function it works and shows the message that the database is created. But when i am calling the saveUser() or createTable() functions, nothing happened, i got no errors and no log messages.

NB : when calling the saveUser() i got the 'save save' message which is outside the two blocks (then and catch), so this tell me that the function is called successfully.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {

  private db: SQLiteObject;
  results = [];

  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) { }

  public createDatabase(): void {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ocp_fuits_database.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      console.log('Database created');
      this.db = db;
      this.createTables();
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  private createTables(): void {
    this.db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`idUser` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `username` TEXT NOT NULL, `password` TEXT NOT NULL)', [])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Table users created');
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  public saveUser(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (\'' + username + '\', \'' + password + '\')', [])
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      console.log(username + password + ' saved');
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    console.log('save save');
  }

  public getUser(username: string): boolean {
    let b: boolean = false;
    this.db.executeSql('select * from users where username like %' + username + '%', [])
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        b = true;
      }
    })
    .catch (e => console.log(e));
    
    return b;
  }

  public getData() {
    this.db.executeSql('select * from users', [])
   .then((data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
          let item = data.rows.item(i);
          this.results.push(item);
        }
   })
   .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    })
    return this.results;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create table SQL you are using **`grave accent`(`)**, that possibly is causing the failures, you don't need that for table name or column name. Try removing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i think at least it must show an error or something, when using then and catch so one of them must be executed.

Comment: Grave accent is used in js for template string, so it's possibly causing error in your case, may not even able to compile & run `executeSql` statement, to be caught in then.catch block. Try putting the whole `db.executeSql` statement in try catch block & print the error, see what you get.